# Samsung oven tripping main fuse

Tags: electrical

I have a Samsung bf641fst and when using the fast heating setting the main fuse trips.

The only way I can get the oven working without tripping the fuse is by using the oven settings without any fan settings included.

Comment: Does it trip immedately when you turn that setting on, or after a while? And are you talking about your main breaker, or the breaker for the oven/range circuit? Also, where are you on this planet?

Comment: What size fuse/breaker?

Comment: Is your main breaker an RCD?

Comment: Yes it's the main breaker. All the power goes off in the house.

Comment: It's almost straight away.

Comment: Yes it is a rcd

Comment: It seems to me that it is a badly designed system in which a ground fault in one circuit trips the main breaker and shuts off power to the entire dwelling! In the US we don't use RCD breakers for the main breaker, do we?

Comment: The fast heating setting may use a very high current in addition to the fan being on. Is this an over-current trip? Does your RCD breaker indicate ground fault trip vs overcurrent trip?

Comment: Where in the world is this?

Comment: @JimStewart -- RCDs are ground-fault (differential) trip *only*, the IEC-land equivalent of our GFCI breakers is a RCBO

Answer (score 1):

### Your oven's fan motor is shot -- replace it

It sounds like your oven's fan motor has a ground fault in it due to insulation breakdown (this is a common cause of motor failure -- its why insulation resistance tests are part of PM for heavy industrial motors).  I'd start by replacing the fan motor as this only happens if the fan is used.  If it continues, I'd keep hunting for the ground fault.

Comment: Is the main breaker a RCD or a combination RCD/AFCB?

Comment: Arc Fault breakers are not used in IEC-based systems to the best of my knowledge @JimStewart